# Changing a value of categorical variable within a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I have a dataframe '''tvdata''' with various traffic data from one website. One of the variables is '''chanel'''. The values of the '''chanel''' variable are '''nl''', '''suma''', '''coop''','''kw''' and other. I would like to change all '''kw''' values within the variable '''chanel''' to '''sea''' and keep everything else in the dataframe unchanged.

How can I do it in R?

Comment: You can do `tvdata$chanel == "kw" <- "sea"`.

Comment: @Maël this solution does not fork for me. 
R is saying that the function "==<-" were not found.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the value of the level. First you should always provide reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42) 
chanel <- sample(c('nl', 'suma', 'coop','kw', 'other'), 15, replace=TRUE)
chanel <- factor(chanel, levels=c('nl', 'suma', 'coop','kw', 'other' ))
chanel
#  [1] nl    other nl    nl    suma  kw    suma  suma  nl    kw    nl    other kw    suma  suma 
# Levels: nl suma coop kw other
```

Notice that the levels are in the order that you provided. Using just `factor(chanel)` would put the levels in alphabetical order. Now change `kw` to `sea`:

```
newlevels <- gsub("kw", "sea", levels(chanel))
levels(chanel) <- newlevels
chanel
#  [1] nl    other nl    nl    suma  sea   suma  suma  nl    sea   nl    other sea   suma  suma 
# Levels: nl suma coop sea other
```